# node-mysql multiple statements in one query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using `nodejs 10.26` + `express 3.5` + `node-mysql 2.1.1` +
`MySQL-Server Version: 5.6.16`.

I got 4 DELETE's and want only 1 Database Request, so i connected the DELETE commands with a ";"... but it  fails always.

```
var sql_string = "DELETE FROM user_tables WHERE name = 'Testbase';";
sql_string += "DELETE FROM user_tables_structure WHERE parent_table_name = 'Testbase';";
sql_string += "DELETE FROM user_tables_rules WHERE parent_table_name = 'Testbase';";
sql_string += "DELETE FROM user_tables_columns WHERE parent_table_name = 'Testbase';";

connection.query(sql_string, function(err, rows, fields) {
   if (err) throw err;
   res.send('true');
});
```

It throws this error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM user_tables_structure WHERE parent_table_name = 'Testbase';DELETE FR' at line 1
```

But if i paste this SQL in PhpMyAdmin it is always successful...

If i write it in single query's its succeed, too.

```
        connection.query("DELETE FROM user_tables WHERE name = 'Testbase'", function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        connection.query("DELETE FROM user_tables_structure WHERE parent_table_name = 'Testbase'", function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;


            connection.query("DELETE FROM user_tables_rules WHERE parent_table_name = 'Testbase'", function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;

                connection.query("DELETE FROM user_tables_columns WHERE parent_table_name = 'Testbase'", function(err, rows, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    res.send('true');
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: That is because you can only have 1 query per request.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

I guess you are using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql). (*but should also work for [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2)*)

The [docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries) says:

> Support for multiple statements is disabled for security reasons (it
>   allows for SQL injection attacks if values are not properly escaped).

### Multiple statement queries

To use this feature you have to enable it for your connection:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

Once enabled, you can execute queries with multiple statements by separating each statement with a semi-colon `;`. Result will be an array for each statement.

### Example

```
connection.query('SELECT ?; SELECT ?', [1, 2], function(err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // `results` is an array with one element for every statement in the query:
  console.log(results[0]); // [{1: 1}]
  console.log(results[1]); // [{2: 2}]
});
```

So if you have enabled the `multipleStatements`, your first code should work.

Comment: Will this work with place holder queries like 

`connection.query('SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author` = ?', ['David'], function (error, results, fields) {
  });`

Comment: @randomness yes, that syntax is correct. Refer to https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#performing-queries

Comment: @majidarif , I think I should make myself more clear. Is it possible to have place holder styled  multi statement query using the node-mysql library?.

Comment: @randomness. Sorry I'm confused by your question. I think it is the same answer. Example `connection.query('SELECT ?, SELECT ?', [1, 2], function (error, results, fields) { });` ?

Comment: @randomness will appreciate an upvote too :). My mistake on the example, use this `SELECT ?; SELECT ?` not `SELECT ?, SELECT ?`.

Comment: @majidarif using this method, are the queries executed in parallel? I cannot seem to find that in the node-mysql documentation.  Thanks.

Comment: @user2278120 not entirely sure but I think you should check the mysql documentation. I think node-mysql sends the whole query and not split the multi query and send 1 by 1. So, I think, it runs synchronously.

Comment: If you want it to run parallel, you should consider using Promise.all() and use single queries for each statement instead of multiple in one statement.

Comment: @majidarif This got me curious, would you mind answering the new question I made? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513128/node-mysql-execute-multiple-queries-the-fastest-possible

Comment: Is there a way to check the result of each query before executing the next one? I only want to run later queries if the first ones succeed

Comment: @RossHarding you can ask it as a separate question. but yes, you can do that.

Comment: Thanks @majidarif, posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230245/node-mysql-multiple-statements-in-one-query-execute-conditionally-on-response-f

Comment: And if you have say just one row in your result from the second SELECT query, you access the 'name' column entry for this via: **result[1][0]['name']**. When comparing a MySQL Boolean entry (implemented as TINYINT, i.e. 0 or 1, in MySQL) you must use a value of 0 or 1, **not**  *false* or *true*.

Answer (score 8):

**Using "multiplestatements: true" like shown below worked for me**

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: '',
    multipleStatements: true
});
connection.connect();
 
var sql = "CREATE TABLE test(id INT DEFAULT 1, name VARCHAR(50));ALTER TABLE test ADD age VARCHAR(10);";
 
connection.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Fetch Data from DB(SQL), the following function would work accurately**

router.get('/', function messageFunction(req, res){
//res.send('Hi Dear Rasikh, Welcome to Test Page.')   //=> One Way
dbConn.query('SELECT COUNT(name) as counted, name, last_name, phone, email from students',
function (err, rows, fields) { // another Way
if (err) throw err

```
  dbConn.query('SELECT name, author from books',
  function (err, rowsBook, fields) { // another Way
      if (err) throw err
    // console.log('The counted is: ', rows[0].counted);    //=> Display in console
    // res.send('Hi Dear Rasikh, Welcome to Test Page.'+ rows[0].counted)  //=> Display in blank page
    
    res.render('main/index',{data:rows, myData:rowsBook});
  })
```

});
});

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Next.js...

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    // Build your multiple MySQL queries here
    const querySql = "DELETE FROM favorites WHERE user = ? AND listingID= ?";
    const querySql2 = "UPDATE properties SET saves = ? WHERE listingid = ?";

    // Pass any params here
    const valuesParams = [user, listingID];
    const valuesParams2 = [upDateSaves, listingID];

    //Execute your multiple MySQL queries here
    const data = await query({query: querySql, values: valuesParams });
    const data2 = await query({query: querySql2, values: valuesParams2 });

    //Combine the results
    const combinedResults = [data, data2];

    res.status(200).json({ 
    text: combinedResults,
   });

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error fetching data' });
  }
}
```