# how to update two rows in a single table with one command in my sql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have  a table

```
 accountdetails
```

with fields

```
customerid,balance,account id
```

Now Im trying to update this through my node app where when I transfer amount, in one record the value should be debited and in another it should be credited

```
var data = {customerid,transferamount,accountid};


 con.query('update accountdetails set balance = balance-? WHERE customerid = ? ,
 [data.transferamount,data.customerid]')

con.query('update  accountdetails set balance = balance+? WHERE accountid = ?,
[data.transferamount,data.accountid]')
```

So currently I have two commands to do this how can we limit this to one command since both are basically updating single table.

Any idea

Comment: I don't think you should. Two queries are fine since the where clause is entirely different.

Comment: To reduce the number of rest calls used I want to make it to single command

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266854/node-mysql-multiple-statement-in-one-query

Comment: dude atomicity will take a toss. Update one by one. Imagine multiple operations on the row with additions and subtractions.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @kawadhiya21, maybe better don't do it... you have to benchmark both cases to figure out performance, but in general, it is possible:

```
sql = 'update accountdetails';
sql += 'set balance = if(customerid = ?, balance - ?, if(accountid = ?, balance + ?, balance) ) ';
sql += 'where customerid = ? or accountid = ?';
con.query(sql, [
    data.customerid,
    data.transferamount,
    data.accountid,
    data.transferamount,
    data.customerid,
    data.accountid
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

Yes these two commands must remain to update your data, since you have different conditions on your commands.

Your first command condition is `WHERE customerid`, while the other command condition is `WHERE accountid`, so it is not possible to combine these into one single command.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best practices is utilising mysql's Triggers. These are programmable database objects that do the job.
What you basically describe is an AFTER UPDATE trigger. For Example:

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER doTheJob AFTER UPDATE ON accountdetails
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
UPDATE accountdetails
SET balance = +? WHERE accountid = ?

  END;
  DELIMITER ;
```

---

More info specifically on AFTER UPDATE triggers [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php)
More info on triggers [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use stored procedures to accomplish this:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

With a stored procedure you can add 3 parameters (customerid, transferamount, accountid) and hide all the internal details of the SQL calls (for instance the solution from Vladimir Kovpak)