# Node.js Error thrown when trying to insert SQL row using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
con.connect(function(err){
if(err) throw err;
console.log("Connected!");
var sql = "USE test; INSERT INTO emails (FirstName, Email) VALUES ('Gaz', 'gmail');";
con.query(sql, function(err, result){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Row inserted at position");
})
```

});

I'm trying to use node.js to insert a new row in an already existing table in MySQL. I connect properly but then an error is thrown in the console log which says the SQL syntax is wrong but I have checked and the sytax set for the sql variable works fine in SQL. The .query(sql, function()) format seems to be correct according to w3schools and other sources. I can't tell what the problem is.

Comment: Change the sql code into `INSERT INTO test.emails (FirstName, Email) VALUES ('Gaz', 'gmail')` i think it's not possible to use multiple sql statements in the node.js query function... edit iám right.. https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23267627/3542461) you should enable multiple statements option when creating connection to be able to use multiple statements. check the answer for more information.

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  multipleStatements: true
});
```