# Node.JS + MySQL - Combining queries for defining vars and selecting data

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, mysql-variables

I have a query that works perfectly in PHPMyAdmin:

```
SET @row_number=0; 
SELECT * FROM blah blah @row_number blah blah;
```

However, when I put this into Node.JS, I can't use a simple `con.query("SET @row_number=0; SELECT * FROM blah blah @row_number blah blah;")` because there's technically 2 queries there. So I tried doing:

```
con.query("SET @row_number=0")
con.query("SELECT * FROM blah blah @row_number blah blah")
```

However, this treats it as if the first query isn't even there. How can I combine these queries into one query? Or, is there any other workaround?

Comment: Are you trying to [generate a row number column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972)? Otherwise, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266854).

Comment: I am trying to do that, however, from that link, I made the query `SELECT * FROM (SELECT  serverusers.serverID, serverusers.userID, serverusers.xpTotal, users.bot @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number FROM users INNER JOIN serverusers ON users.userID = serverusers.userID WHERE users.bot = 'false' && serverID = 318467989655781389 ORDER BY xpTotal DESC) AS t WHERE t.userID = 289233475481894914 JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r);` Have I done something wrong? Because there's a syntax error near '@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number FROM users INNER JOIN serverusers ON users.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for node-mysql:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

(taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266854) answer)

Comment: Im using the `mysql` library not the `node-mysql` library. Will it still work?