# Node.js MySQL connection, queries order and Event Loop

Tags: mysql, node.js

Let's see this example

```
conn.query('SET @v = 1;', (err) => {
    conn.query('SELECT @v;', (err, res) => {
       // res contains @v = 1 or 2 ?
    });
});

conn.query('SET @v = 2;', (err) => {
    conn.query('SELECT @v;', (err, res) => {
        // res contains @v = 1 or 2 ?
    });
});
```

Does `mysql`/`mysql2` node packages guarantee MySQL queries order or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both mysql and mysql2 preserve the order. In following example order of execution is indicated by number

```
conn.query('query 1', (err) => {
    conn.query('query 3', (err, res) => {
    });
});

conn.query('query 2', (err) => {
    conn.query('query 4', (err, res) => {
    });
});
```

First, "query 1" and "query 2" are placed to command queue. Then after "query 1" is complete "query 3" is added to queue ( now it's "query 2, query 3" ). After "query 2" is complete it's callback function is called and as a result "query 4" is added to queue.

This is more of a protocol property, not just driver's feature. Mysql protocol only allows you to send next command only after current command if fully complete, and is in a way "half duplex". The only way to actually run two sql queries in parallel is to open 2 separate connections.

Comment: Thank you. It means, that both 'SELECT @v;` from the example in the initial post return `2` as result