# SQL Query functioning when executed in Db Browser for SQLite but not when implemented in node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, discord.js

SQL Statement working perfectly fine when ran in DB Browser for SQLite but not in node.js code. Are there any changes that I need to make?

I created a query that would INSERT values into a table if the specified values did not exist, or UPDATE values if they do exist. 
When ran in the DB Browser for SQLite, the query worked perfectly but when I tried to implement it in my code, the UPDATE statement works but not the INSERT statement, with no errors being returned. Why is that?

```
 let sql2 = `UPDATE inventory 
  SET item_name = '${itemChosen}', item_amount = ${amountChosen) where discordId = '${user}';

 INSERT INTO inventory (discordId,item_name,item_amount) 
 select '${user}','${itemChosen}',${amountChosen}
 WHERE (Select changes() = 0);`;
 db.all(sql2, [], (err, rows) => {
  if (err) {
     throw (err)
    }
  message.reply("Item purchased!");
})
```

The UPDATE statement works fine, but the INSERT statement will never get executed. No error messages are returned.

Comment: This might be usefull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266854/node-mysql-multiple-statements-in-one-query

Comment: You can only execute one query per request.