# My query works in MySQL workbench and phpmyadmin but not in node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm trying to get a query to work in node.js but I can't get it to work. I've tested it in MySQL workbench and in phpmyadmin, and the query works in both. Can someone see what the error is?

I've tried adding backticks to the query, didn't work. Tried to use " instead of ` to start the query, didn't work.

```
app.get('/meetings/add', (req, res) => {
    const { meetingsubject, meetingdescription, bulletpoints, bulletpointslength } = req.query;
    var bulletPointQuery = " INSERT INTO `bulletpoints` (`idmeeting`, `bulletpointname`) VALUES ";
    var allBulletPoints = bulletpoints.split(',');
    for(var i = 0; i < bulletpointslength; i++){
        if(i === bulletpointslength - 1){
            bulletPointQuery = bulletPointQuery  + "(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '" + allBulletPoints[i] + "');";
        }else {
            bulletPointQuery = bulletPointQuery  + "(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '" + allBulletPoints[i] + "'),"
        }
    }
    const insertMeeting = "BEGIN; INSERT INTO `meetings` (`meetingsubject`, `meetingdescription`) VALUES ('" + meetingsubject +"', '" + meetingdescription + "');" + bulletPointQuery + "COMMIT;";

    connection.query(insertMeeting, (err, results) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.send(err);
        }else{
            console.log("yup");
            res.send("sucessfully added meeting");
        }
    });

});
```

this is the error:

> code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
>    errno: 1064,
>    sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `meetings` (`meetingsubject`, `meetingdescription`) VALUES ('yayeet'' at line 1",
>     sqlState: '42000',
>     index: 0,
>     sql: "BEGIN; INSERT INTO `meetings` (`meetingsubject`, `meetingdescription`) VALUES ('yayeet', 'yaeter'); INSERT INTO `bulletpoints` (`idmeeting`, `bulletpointname`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'yeet (07:30)'),(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'wwee (07:30)');COMMIT;"

**EDIT**
The query i'm trying to work with:

```sql
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `meetings` (`meetingsubject`, `meetingdescription`) 
    VALUES ('yayeet', 'yaeter');
INSERT INTO `bulletpoints` (`idmeeting`, `bulletpointname`)
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'yeet (07:30)'),
    (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'wwee (07:30)');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: don't have an answer, but a suggestion: `const bulletPointQuery = "INSERT INTO \`bulletpoints\` (\`idmeeting\`, \`bulletpointname\`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '" + bulletpoints.split(',').join("'),(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '") + "');";`

Comment: Are you using node-mysql? I don't think it supports doing multiple statements in the same query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266854/node-mysql-multiple-statements-in-one-query

Comment: @RobStreeting Thank you very much! Just had to add multipleStatements: true to the connection...