# node-mysql multiple statements in one query, execute conditionally on response from each

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I want to execute multiple queries in one API call, but I only want to execute them conditionally based on the response of the previous one. How can I go about implementing this?

I've seen that I can do something like below to execute multiple queries.

```
connection.query('SELECT * ...; SELECT * ...', [1, 2], function(err, results) {
   if (err) throw err;
});
```

But how do I await the response of the first before conditionally executing the second?

Comment: You can't do them in one query. Do the second one in the callback function of the first.

Comment: stored procedures can be used for this else you could run them one by one.

Comment: I've heard that using queries in the callbacks of other queries can open you up to SQL injection attacks. @Barmar Can you speak to this at all?

Comment: Only if you're inserting the results of one query into the SQL string of the next, rather than using parameters.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234298/selecting-from-2-tables-at-one-time-in-node-js/60234412#60234412 for another question about querying from multiple tables at once.

Comment: can you give a sample for the actual queries you want to do, and the logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not supported (unless written in database itself - like tsql, plsql or others).
What you can do - is execute query, wait for its results and then execute another accordingly.
example:

```
const query1 = '.....';
connection.query(query1, [...params1], function(err, results) {
   if (err) throw err;

   const query2 = condition ? '....' : '........';
   connection.query(query2, [...params2], ......);
});
```

and so on in and in (callback hell).

You can do it a bit better like that (i presume connection is:  mysql.getConnection and is properly set without errors there).  `params<X>` is an array with parameters for the query.

```
const executeQuery = async (con, query, params) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      con.query(query, params, (err, result) => {
          if (err) { return reject(err); }

          return resolve(result);
      });
   });
}


mysql.getConnection((err, connection) => {
   if (err) { throw err; }

   try {
      const query1 = '<some query>';
      const result1 = await executeQuery(query1, params1);

      const query2 = (condition on query1) ? '<query>' : '<other query>';
      const result2 = await executeQuery(connection, query2, params2);

      const query3 = (condition you want) ? '<query for that condition>' : '<or not>';
      const result3 = await executeQuery(connection, query3, params3);
   } catch (err) {
     connection.release();
     throw err;
   } // if newest node  you can use  finally block and have only one  connection.release();

   connection.release();
}
```