# How do I iterate of the object containing queries, and execute them all

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have an object that looks like this:

```
let queries = [
  {
    name: "checkUsers",
    query: 'select * from users where inactive = 1'
  },
  {
    name: "checkSubscriptions",
    query: 'select * from subscriptions where invalid = 1'
  }
]
```

I am making an AWS Lambda function that will iterate these queries, and if any of them returns a value, I will send an email.

I have come up with this pseudo code:

```
for (let prop in queries) {  

  const result = await mysqlConnector.runQuery(prop.query).catch(async error => {
    // handle error in query    
  });

  if (result.length < 0){
    // send email
  }
}

return;
```

I am wondering is this ideal approach? I need to iterate all the object queries.

Comment: Just for clarification, do you want to send mail every time if a response returns? or just when one of the response return first?

Comment: For all queries that return something, I will send the email. Others will be ignored.

Comment: I would map the "queries" array's object into request promises, and would use the promise.all with a little workaround, or if the lambda node runtime is 12.9 or higher I would use promise.allSettled.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with what you are trying to achieve but there are few changes you could do

- Try to use `Promise.all` if you can. This will speed up the overall process as things will execute in parallel. It will depend on number of queries as well.
- Try leverage executing multiple statements in one query. This way you will make one call and then you can add the logic to identify. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23267627/1021796)