# Knex - MySQL How could I execute multiple statements in a single JavaScript string?

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I'm trying to carry out some SQL instructions inside my migrations file by using knex.
To get more flexibility, I'd like to put all my related SQL inside a single string.
The problem is: When I have two or more statements inside the string, MySQL isn't able to
understand it and throws the following error:
"`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server..."`

I believe that happens due to \n, \s, and \t characters which are inside my raw result.
I've tried `.replace(/\n/g, '')` and `.replace(/\t/g, '')`, however it didn't make any effect on it.

In this case, is there some way to execute my RAW string containing multiple statements?

Thanks a lot.

My original method:

```
// Fail
    exports.up = async (knex) => {
      try {
        console.info('Migrating CLIENT...');
        return await knex.raw(
          `
          DELETE FROM monthly_consumption;
          DELETE FROM project;
          DELETE FROM project_client;
          DELETE FROM client;
          ALTER TABLE client DROP PRIMARY KEY;
          ALTER TABLE client ADD id BIGINT auto_increment;
          ALTER TABLE client ADD CONSTRAINT client_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);
        `
            .replace(/\n/g, '')
            .replace(/\t/g, ' ')
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('******** ERROR ********\n', err);
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    };
```

On the other hand, If I run the following, it works, that is, if it contains only one statement, it's gonna work fine.

```
// Success
exports.up = async (knex) => {
  try {
    console.info('Migrating CLIENT...');
    return await knex.raw(
      `
      DELETE FROM monthly_consumption;
    `
        .replace(/\n/g, '')
        .replace(/\t/g, ' ')
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('******** ERROR ********\n', err);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

I tried to put all that in a single line too, but it fails again:

```
// Fail
exports.up = async (knex) => {
  try {
    console.info('Migrating CLIENT...');
    return await knex.raw(
      `
      DELETE FROM monthly_consumption; DELETE FROM project;
    `
        .replace(/\n/g, '')
        .replace(/\t/g, ' ')
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('******** ERROR ********\n', err);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

Original SQL output from the last one example:

```
migration failed with error: Error:       DELETE FROM monthly_consumption; DELETE FROM project;     - ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM project' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. It was related to MySQL itself. We need to enable multiple statement feature. Inside the knexfile.js, I simply inserted:

```
 multipleStatements: true
```

At last, it worked perfectly.

Comment: with migrations that should be fine, but remember that it may make your app to be vulnerable for sql-injection, because values are not sent to DB as bindings anymore https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266854/node-mysql-multiple-statements-in-one-query/23267627

Comment: Hey @MikaelLepistö That's it. I'm aware of that. For a while, that was the best solution for me. I've plans to implement some mechanisms to avoid sql-injection in my app. Thanks for your feedback.