# NodeJS MySQL Update If Null

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm using MySQL with NodeJS and I'm just pretty new.

I want to UPDATE col value if it's null else UPDATE for another col.

Simply like that: If col1 is null UPDATE else UPDATE col2.

```
    app.post('/api/update', (req, res) => {
        const convidn = req.body.conversationid
        const currentuser = req.body.current
     
    
       var sql = "UPDATE messages SET whodeleted='"+currentuser+"' WHERE converid = '" + convidn + "'";
```

That overwrites column value. I just want to if "whodeleted" is not null UPDATE for "whodeleted2" colum.

```
        db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Number of records deleted: " + result.affectedRows);
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

But your code is **vulnerable** to **sql inject** please read [Preventing SQL injection in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js) to so how you  can avoid it

```
UPDATE messages 
SET 
    whodeleted = CASE
        WHEN whodeleted IS NULL THEN ?
        ELSE whodeleted
    END,
    col2 = CASE
        WHEN whodeleted IS NULL THEN col2
        ELSE 'test'
    END
WHERE
    converid = ?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. But I have a trouble with multiline SQL query for NodeJS. How can i handle with that?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266854/node-mysql-multiple-statements-in-one-query and please accept the answer