# Syntax error with IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT (NODE JS)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to write an SQL query that will update an entry if it exists and insert a new one if it does not exist. The UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY option doesn't work because I am not querying by the primary key. The SQL statement I am referring to is in the sql.query() function below. I have also added the error message.

```
  Asset.create = (newAsset, result) => {
      sql.query(
        `if exists(SELECT * from asset WHERE 
         AssetId="${newAsset.AssetId}" AND 
         AccountID="${newAsset.AccountId}") BEGIN UPDATE asset set 
         Amount="${newAsset.Amount}" where AssetId="${newAsset.AssetId}" 
         AND AccountID="${newAsset.AccountId}" End else begin INSERT 
         INTO asset SET ? end`,
        newAsset,
        (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error", err);
            result(err, null);
            return;
          }
    
          result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...newAsset });
        }
      );
    };
```

**Error message:**

*sqlMessage: `You have an error in your SQL  syntax; check the manual that corresponds to  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if exists(SELECT * from asset  WHERE AssetId="bitcoin" AND AccountID="2c341fed-cf' at line 1`,*

Comment: such a construct is only allowed in functions and procedures and are **not** valid sql code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, compound statement syntax such as `BEGIN ... END` and `IF ... THEN ... END IF` is supported only in stored routines. You can't use such statements when executing them directly from clients.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html says:

> This section describes the syntax for the BEGIN ... END compound statement and other statements that can be used in the body of stored programs: Stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events.

In the example you show, you seem to be trying to update a row, and if the row does not exist, then insert it.

One solution if you have a primary key or unique key on the table is to use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO asset (AssetId, AccountId, Amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Amount = VALUES(Amount);
```

I'm supposing for the above example that AssetId and AccountId are the primary key.

An alternative is to try the UPDATE first, and in the callback, check `result.affectedRows`. If this is zero, then try the INSERT.

Comment: AssetId and AccountId are not the primary keys which is why the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE approach wouldn't work. However, your alternative approach worked perfectly. Thank you. I have been trying to figure this one out for days :)

Answer (score 0):

this is no valid sql code

In SQL you would write something like

```
SELECT
if (exists(SELECT * from asset WHERE AssetId="${newAsset.AssetId}" AND AccountID="${newAsset.AccountId}") 
, @sql := 'UPDATE asset set Amount="${newAsset.Amount}" where AssetId="${newAsset.AssetId}" AND AccountID="${newAsset.AccountId}" ',
@sql := 'INSERT INTO asset SET ? ');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

but this is multi query which mus be [eanabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266854/node-mysql-multiple-statements-in-one-query)

it needs still some work ys you have to many quotes