# SQL Query working in Workbench but getting `ER_PARSE_ERROR` via NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, server, last-insert-id

I'm sending a query to create a user in the DB by doing:

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, Permissions) VALUES ('${req.body.username}', '${hashedPassword}','${req.body.FirstName}','${req.body.LastName}', 'basic_client'); SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = LAST_INSERT_ID();`;
```

I haven't yet implemented protection for SQL injection but will later (suggestions welcome).

The issue is that my server gets
`code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR', errno: 1064, sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 1",`

Any help is appreciated!

### I've tried:

- I tried multi-line string, and the last line seems to cause the issue, normal INSERT INTO is working.
- I tried logging the output and when I try running the exact same query via the Workbench, it works just fine.
- LAST_INSERT_ID() alone also works in the Workfbench
- I replaced the whole SQL code with just `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and it worked via the server. But nothing else works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the missing link in this post --> [node-mysql multiple statements in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266854/node-mysql-multiple-statements-in-one-query)

Its not because the SQL is invalid, but rather because Node --> DB queries are by default limited to a single operation in order to combat SQL injection. It is possible to override this, but I'll play it safe and send 2 requests instead.

On that note, the setup works when 2 requests are sent, it works beautifully!